# String manipulation in r where contents of interest are in a different order

Tags: r, regex, string

I have dataframe where I am attempting to extract content of a column and then append it to the dataframe as a new column.

For example my dataframe looks like:

```
> head(df)  
id event_params  
1 {"type":"L","maximumangle":-87.618,"duration":25}  
2 {"type":"L","maximumangle":1.62,"duration":25}  
3 {"maximumangle":-29.661,"type":"L","duration":20}
```

I wish to extract the maximum angle, and then append this to the existing dataframe as a new column titled maximumangle. My initial thought was to use the *grep* function. However, since maximumangle does not appear in the same order in each row, this will not work.

What can I do to achieve what I want?

Comment: Could you please post the `dput` of the example

Comment: Have you considered splitting the string between "maximumangle" and a comma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Parse the last column using `fromJSON` in the rjson package.  This adds all the JSON data.

```
library(rjson)

L <- lapply(as.character(DF$event_params), fromJSON)
cbind(DF, do.call("rbind", lapply(L, as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
```

giving:

```
  id                                      event_params type maximumangle duration
1  1 {"type":"L","maximumangle":-87.618,"duration":25}    L      -87.618       25
2  2    {"type":"L","maximumangle":1.62,"duration":25}    L        1.620       25
3  3 {"maximumangle":-29.661,"type":"L","duration":20}    L      -29.661       20
```

**2)** We can simplify this slightly if you really only need `maximumangle`:

```
maximumangle <- function(x) fromJSON(as.character(x))$maximumangle
transform(DF, maximumangle = sapply(DF$event_params, maximumangle, USE.NAMES = FALSE))
```

giving:

```
  id                                      event_params maximumangle
1  1 {"type":"L","maximumangle":-87.618,"duration":25}      -87.618
2  2    {"type":"L","maximumangle":1.62,"duration":25}        1.620
3  3 {"maximumangle":-29.661,"type":"L","duration":20}      -29.661
```

### Note

We assumed that the input in reproducible form is given by:

```
Lines <- '
id event_params  
1 {"type":"L","maximumangle":-87.618,"duration":25}  
2 {"type":"L","maximumangle":1.62,"duration":25}  
3 {"maximumangle":-29.661,"type":"L","duration":20}'
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: When I attempted to run this I received an error as follows: 
`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'integer' `

Comment: @Michael - try `lapply(as.character(DF$event_params), fromJSON)` - you probably have a `factor` column in your real data that is causing an issue.

Comment: Thank you, I had the column entered as a factor data type. I appreciate the help. It's astonishing to me not only how fast you came up with, but how efficient the answer is. I only wish to be this skillful one day.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** We can use `str_extract` from `stringr` by using a regex lookaround to match the string 'maximumangle' followed by a quote (`"`) and colon (`:`) and extract the pattern the follows it i.e. zero or more `-` (`-*`) followed by numbers with digits (`[0-9.]+`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(maximumangle =  as.numeric(str_extract(event_params, 
                        '(?<=maximumangle":)-*[0-9.]+')))
#  id                                      event_params maximumangle
#1  1 {"type":"L","maximumangle":-87.618,"duration":25}      -87.618
#2  2    {"type":"L","maximumangle":1.62,"duration":25}        1.620
#3  3 {"maximumangle":-29.661,"type":"L","duration":20}      -29.661
```

---

**2)** Or the same can be done with `base R` using `regexpr/regmatches`

```
df$maximumangle <-  as.numeric(regmatches(df$event_params, 
     regexpr('(?<=maximumangle":)-*[0-9.]+', df$event_params, perl = TRUE)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, event_params = c("{\"type\":\"L\",\"maximumangle\":-87.618,\"duration\":25}", 
"{\"type\":\"L\",\"maximumangle\":1.62,\"duration\":25}", "{\"maximumangle\":-29.661,\"type\":\"L\",\"duration\":20}"
)), .Names = c("id", "event_params"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: This literally did everything I needed in only two lines of code. Do you mind explaining what is going on? I would love to understand!

Comment: One more thing, what does the `%>%` do/accomplish?

Comment: @Michael It connects the lhs expression  with the rhs of the `%>%`,