# Error when mapping function / Works fine when I run it manually piece by piece; Why?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, purrr

I apologize for the size of the code in this question, but since I was not able to identify where it goes wrong, I thought best to provide it as close to the original as possible.

I have the following environment, with two functions:

First function is supposed to take as input a series of paths to read .csv files(`EMPRESA_reads`), bind them and export:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(glue)
library(data.table)

read_compile = function(EMPRESA_reads,Export_path){

  cat("Reading EMPRESA files... \n")
  EMPRESA_Imported = map(EMPRESA_reads,fread,sep = ",")

  cat("Binding EMPRESA rows... \n")
  EMPRESA_Imported = EMPRESA_Imported%>%
    lapply(., mutate_if, is.integer, as.character)%>%
    bind_rows()

  cat("Exporting file... \n")
  setwd(Export_path)
  fwrite(EMPRESA_Imported,file = "EMPRESA_compiled.csv",sep = ";")

  cat("Done! \n")
}
```

Second function is supposed to take as input a identifier string (`RFB_date`), generate the correct paths for input in the first function, then call it:

```
Merge_by_date = function(RFB_date){

  cat(glue("Starting RFB_date {RFB_date}"))
  cat("\n")

  EMPRESA_path = glue("path/RFB_Empresas_{RFB_date}")
  Export_path = glue("path/RFB_Socios_{RFB_date}/With_EMPRESA_info")

  # Creating list of files to be read in each folder
  # Check the file name pattern and adjust accordingly

  EMPRESA_files = list.files(path = EMPRESA_path, pattern = "^empresas")
  EMPRESA_reads = glue("{EMPRESA_path}/{EMPRESA_files}")

  read_compile(EMPRESA_reads,Export_path)
}
```

I want to run this second function for multiple dates, so I map them:

```
RFB_dates = c("201902",
              "201906",
              "201911",
              "202002")

map(RFB_dates,Merge_by_date)
```

On the first run (for `RFB_dates[1]`), however, I get this output:

```
Starting RFB_date 201902
Reading EMPRESA files... 
Binding EMPRESA rows... 

 Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'char'
```

Which indicates some problem when binding elements of the `EMPRESA_Imported` list in this run, but not before.

**The thing is: when manually running the function a single time (instead of mapping it), it does not throw out this error, performing the `bind_rows()` as it should**

I have not figured out why would this happen, and appreciate any help!

About the .csv files I'm reading: they are pretty big (~15gb in total) but contain nothing out of ordinary: simply columns with string and numeric data.

Thank you!

Comment: You've seen this?[SOF?s80974671](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184851/rstudio-error-string-elt-can-only-be-applied-to-a-character-vector-not-a), well, not the whole url, but look up SOF ? 34184851. Essentially suggests, due to continued wrestlling, debugging, writing & etc. just shut down your session and start anew. But not having the data, don't know if you have factors in your columns & etc, perhaps also this [SOF?s49062888](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49062888/string-manipulation-in-r-where-contents-of-interest-are-in-a-different-order)

Comment: you should try to make your example minimal, it is not sure if the problem comes from glue, purr or data.table. `bind_rows` seems to be the problem, so you should strip out all those loops and focus on bind_rows case that raises error.

Comment: @jangorecki, the problem is: if I do anything less than what is shown, there is no error. Even running without a map (only running the function) works, with the exact data that a map would do first. I've put all the layers to this example exactly because they all exist and I am unable to rule them out as a possible source of the error

Edit: anyway, that might be a problem of how I decide to ask questions here... I'll try to stick to more specific issues

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
read_compile <- function(EMPRESA_reads,Export_path){

cat("Reading EMPRESA files... \n")
EMPRESA_Imported = map(EMPRESA_reads, ~ fread(.x, sep = ","))

cat("Binding EMPRESA rows... \n")
EMPRESA_Imported <- EMPRESA_Imported %>%
map(~ mutate_if(.x, is.integer(), as.character())) %>%
bind_rows()

cat("Exporting file... \n")
setwd(Export_path)
fwrite(EMPRESA_Imported,file = "EMPRESA_compiled.csv",sep = ";")

 cat("Done! \n")
}
```

Comment: Well, got a different error:
`  Error in is.integer() : 0 arguments passed to 'is.integer' which requires 1 `